# jquery mobile: text input resizes after typing

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

i'm currently working at a jquery mobile project in combination with apache cordova / phonegap. im trying to implement a simple user-interface, but it happens a problem when using the text input.

when i am touching the input and typing some words in it, everythings fine. after leaving the input, it resizes to a smaller size and the label belonging to it too. i tried a lot and googled, but i got no solution.

i'll post you my code and hope, that someone has got a hint.

thank you.

```
    <div data-role="page">

        <!-- data-position="fixed" verursacht Probleme mit den Textinputs -->

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
            <h1>Storage Test</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

            <input type="text" name="filename" id="filename" value=""/>

            <!-- Console -->
            <ul data-inset="true" data-role="listview" id="console" style="width:50%">
                <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">Console</li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Control -->
            <ul data-inset="true" data-role="listview" id="control" style="width:48%; position:fixed; top:58px; right: 1%">

                <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">Control</li>

                <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="filename">Filename:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="filename" id="filename" value=""/>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <button data-theme="b" type="submit">Save to file system</button>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Have you used viewport <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/> in your HEAD?.

Comment: Yes i do use this meta-Tag. I was able to notice, that removing the data-role="fieldcontain" attribute makes it working, but this is no real good solution or?

Comment: Tell me also are you using jQM 1.2 or beta 1.3?

Comment: I will try to test it myself. One more thing, are you testing this on iOS or Android?

Comment: But you can make a workaround, instead of fieldcontain create a grid with two rows, put a label into top one and input into the bottom one.

Comment: i'm testing on android. samsung galaxy tab 10.1n with android 3. thank you!